# Calculating and grouping by great circle distance in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables, one that roughly looks like:

```
client_ip  server_ip  speed
---------  ---------  -----
1.2.3.4    9.1.2.3    100
1.2.3.5    9.1.2.3    1033
```

And another that has geo data:

```
ip       latitude    longitude
-------  --------    ---------
1.2.3.4  13.75       100.21
1.2.3.5  21.1234     141.21
9.1.2.3  13.75       99.21
```

I would like to write a select query that figures out the great circle distance between the two IP addresses, groups by it, and calculates the average speed.  So, for example, the ideal output would be something like:

```
distance  avg(speed)
--------  ----------
21        99
100       1234
```

While I know there are [good resources out there](https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlsearch_v3#findnearsql) on getting the great circle distance in SQL, my head is a little cloudy on how to efficiently join the two tables, since both are rather large (millions of rows).

Any advice?

Comment: Do you actually want to retrieve all these resulting rows, or are you only interested in the shortest or longest paths. Because comparing distances can be cheaper than actually computing distances. E.g. you could turn angles on the sphere into 3D coordinates, and simply compare distances using these, i.e. direct straight line instead of geodesics (= great circle segment).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that the IPs in the geo data table are unique, it is actually not a very expensive join.  Even though you are joining from a table with non-unique values in the server_ip column, you don't have to tell the system that it is an outer join -- for each line in the "speed" table, there will be one, and only one, entry in the IP table matching the client_ip, and one, and only one, entry in the IP table matching the server_ip.  So, you can use inner joins without any trouble.

```
SELECT <c.client_ip to s.server_ip distance calc> AS Distance, AVG(sp.speed) AS AvgSpeed
FROM speedTable sp JOIN geoTable c
    ON sp.client_ip = c.client_ip JOIN geoTable s
    ON sp.server_ip = s.server_ip
WHERE 1 = 1 --whatever your where clause is
GROUP BY <c.client_ip to s.server_ip distance calc>
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, the join probably isn't the slow part of this query, it's going to be the distance calculation on each row...

```
SELECT
  client_ip,
  server_ip,
  avg(speed),
  {your distance calculation} AS distance
FROM 
  speeds
  JOIN geo AS geo_client ON geo_client.ip=speeds.client_ip 
  JOIN geo AS geo_server ON geo_server.ip=speeds.server_ip
GROUP BY
  distance
```

There's your join, but notice that the distance calculation is done on each row, with millions of rows, you're going to take a big hit there. You could try a few things, maybe take a look at these other posts:

- [Distance Calculation with huge SQL Server database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8526075/distance-calculation-with-huge-sql-server-database)
- [Optimising SQL distance query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2441757/optimising-sql-distance-query)
- [SQL Get Distance from Longitude and Latitude](http://www.n-smith.com/index.cfm/my-blog/2008-08-15-sql-get-distance-from-longitude-and-latitude/)